# Select all data from database where title is lorem ipsum in Laravel 4

Tags: mysql, select, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am using Laravel 4 Eloquent to select data from database. It works fine.

But now I want to Select all data from database where the title matches "Lorem Ipsum"

It Should retrieve all the titles which match the provided keywords.

Trying to make a database search in Laravel and hence I require this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for "LIKE".

This should work

```
$searchString = 'Lorem Ipsum';

$result = myModel::where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchString . '%')->get();
```

or if you want to limit your results.

```
$limit = 10;

$result = myModel::where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchString . '%')->take($limit)->get();
```

Source: My brain and http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent

Comment: Really thanks for the code. This worked perfect for me. I was trying the implement the same LIKE, but i was going wrong in writing %.

But I want to paginate them. When i try Paginate, it gives error

Comment: What error did it throw? AFAIK, you can just replace `->get()` with `->paginate()`

Comment: @Melvin Thanks alot, I was new. I was just trying along with get().

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this

```
$results = DB::select('select * from posts where title = ?', array('Lorem Ipsum'));
```

Comment: public function getSearch()
 {
  $posts = DB::select('select * from posts where title = ?', array('Lorem Ipsum'));
  return $posts;
  
 }

I just changed this to my Controller. but it returns nothing

shows "[]" when I run the page

Comment: do you have data to match the search?

Comment: Hey I am sorry, "Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet" this was my title. Now it shows the results. But problem is it is showing only one result. But I have 5 titles matching the same. How to retrieve all of them

Comment: Also, I want to search using tags. I want to search results if they type LOREM, LOREM IPSUM, IPSUM etc etc. just like a common search.